# How these Test Strategies function in A/B Testing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics, sitecore8.2

Using Sitecore 8.2
I have 4 questions but all are very much related.
There are some test Strategies defined in the Marketing control panel > Test lab

```
Subgroup Round Robin
Sticky
Round Robin
Random
```

1. I created a simple A/B test with two variations and set the Test strategy as Random. When browsing the page, I'm expecting that the variations will load randomly on page refresh. Is this correct?
2. Can someone please give some brief or link/document which has details about these ?
3. When creating a test, we go through 3 tabs full of configuration options. Yet Test Strategy is not there. After creating the test, it seems, we need to find our way to the Test Lab for just this one config option. Any reason for separating this option.
4. Where/how do I give the value that 50% should see version A and the rest, version B.